# Possibility of triple screen setup with two graphic cards

Tags: 13.10, compiz, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I'm trying to get my favorite triple display setup (3x1 Portrait █ █ █) running under ubuntu/xubuntu 13.10 yet had no gratifying results so far. Ubuntu crashed Compiz repeatedly. And only offered TwinView plus xterm at best. [Xinerama](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multihead) failed to work too.

Setup consists of 2 Nvidia Quattro FX 580 and 3 1920x1200 Displays (2*DVI 1*Displayport). Each of the cards is capable of running two displays and the setup worked well in Mosaic Mode as a unified Display before. Any recommendations for a promising drivers/versions & window manager combination?